# Do medic and ammo bags run out after a certain number of uses, or after a certain amount of health/ammo dispensed?

Tags: payday-the-heist

Payday: The Heist contains medic and ammo bags which replenish health and ammunition, respectively.  After a while, these bags become depleted and vanish.  I haven't been able to figure out if a bag disappears after it has been used a certain number of times, or if it disappears after replenishing a certain amount of health or ammo.

I ask because if the first case is true, then I should avoid using bags when I'm at 75% or higher on health / ammo, because I'll be effectively wasting a use. If the latter is true, then I can use bags whenever I want, because I won't be hurting any other members of my team.

**Do medic and ammo bags run out after a certain number of uses, or after a certain amount of health / ammo has been dispensed?"**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's both actually!** Ammo bags and Doctor bags act differently in this regard.

- [Ammo bags](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Ammo_bag) have a set *amount* of ammunition that depletes depending on how much you take. It'll initially have enough to fully reload a weapon 4 times, which can be increased up to 10 times through upgrading.
- [Doctor bags](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Ammo_bag), however, have a set number of *uses*. It starts off at 2 and increases to 5 through upgrading.

Due to this difference in functionality, feel free to just top off your ammo when you need it from an Ammo bag, but don't do the same for the Doctor bag because you'll essentially be wasting a use that may be better off saved for someone else or when you really need it.